# Why does new javascript script make Capybara tests fail?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have written a new JS script for submitting HTTP requests for certain click events. Currently in runs against all pages in my rails app. (not ideal but I figured it wouldn't cause serious issues for the time being. However, its presence makes a huge number of capybara tests fails. I have no idea why.

```js
function onCheckboxClick() {
  const url = $(this).attr("data-action")
  const data = {
    method: "PATCH",
    body: JSON.stringify({ confidential: this.checked }),
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': Rails.csrfToken(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  fetch(url, data)
    .then(response => { return response.json() })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#invoice_confidential")
  checkboxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("click", onCheckboxClick)
  })
})
```

Comment: If you add some tests it would be helpfull. And the rspec configuration files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are using ES6 syntax I don't know what browser you are using for your tests but that could be the problem, maybe it needs to be compiled to ES5.

But you didn't provide enough information. What Rails version are you using? Are you using Webpacker? Do you have Babel setup? Maybe you can share some configuration stuff.

Comment: You were exactly right! By changing everything to ES5, all the problems were resolved. Thank you!